# how to ignore callback function?

Tags: cakephp, callback, cakephp3

I have a beforeFind callback in my model file. And in Controller file I have the below code : 
`$this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('user_id'));` . How can I add `applyOptions` here to ignore `beforeFind()` callback in UsersTable.php ?

Comment: `$this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('user_id'), ['foo' => 'bar']);`, then look at the `$options` array for this in your `beforeFind` callback and return early if it's there.